# Is there a way to make this repetitive code more efficient?

Tags: python

I have this code with a lot of redundancies. Are there any methods to reduce the code's size?

```
def activate_rename(self):
        global h
        i_activate_rename=0
        if grp3.click=="Yes":
            for i_activate_rename in range(4):
                grp4.radionbutton_list[i_activate_rename].config(state=NORMAL)
                i_activate_rename+=1
        else:
            for i_activate_rename in range(4):
                grp4.radionbutton_list[i_activate_rename].config(state=DISABLED)
                grp5.radionbutton_list[i_activate_rename].config(state=DISABLED)
                grp6.radionbutton_list[i_activate_rename].config(state=DISABLED)

            i_activate_rename=0
            for i_activate_rename in range(h):
                list_input3[i_activate_rename].config(state=DISABLED)
                list_input2[i_activate_rename].config(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: Depends what it is supposed to do

Comment: you could probably ask this in code review community, not stack overflow.

Comment: if you post on Code Review please read the help center pages like [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - in its current form this post would be considered off-topic because there is little context about what the code does and how the function is used, plus the title is about CR goals instead of describing what the code does

Comment: The only redundancies are setting the same state to multiple button lists. Just replace those with loops.

Comment: `for grp in [grp4, grp5, grp6]: ...`

Comment: Thank you all for the tipps. Im new and didn't know the difference with Code Review !
Barmar: it works, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove definition of `i_activate_rename` variable in line 3. When you enter the for loop you redefine it as an iteration variable, so it is created regardless and its lifespan does not transgress that code of block. You don't need to redefine it later in your code, as it is set to `0` in the beginning of each loop block.

In the first for loop, you're increasing the the iteration variable by two explicitly with `i_activate_rename+=1` and implicitly when each loop finishes. You can instruct your range sequential, to produce every second integer: `range(0, 4, 2)`. It will return `0, 2` in consecutive loops.

Comment: Tried and worked. Thank you very much !! It's a subtelty for the newbie that I am. Happy to have learned this rule from you